# 64-bit C++ binary consumes huge memory even binary size is huge

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, x86-64

When we compiled our C++ apps in 32-bit everything was still ok.  When we ported everything to 64-bit the binary sizes more than doubled! And when we ran the binaries, only one ran because it was hogging all the RAM. We've done all the 64-bit porting so that compilation is successful. However, during runtime, the memory consumption goes up to the limit.  It doesn't crash though. It just runs until it stops and no core file is generated.  Does anyone have any suggestion where I should start in investigating this?

Our compilation options are:

> -D_*linux*_ -pthread -fexceptions -c -Wall -DSTL_HAS_DEFAULT_ARGS -DUsePthread -D_REENTRANT
>   -Dx86_64 -DLINUX  -g  -O2

The ulimit info on our linux machine is:

```
-bash-4.1$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30405
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 4096
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 10240
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Our 24 binaries create in total about 4000 threads (thus the -u 10240) created mostly for message listening purposes.
It also constantly searches/maintains db connection.
The stack size -s was 512 before but we changed to 4096 just to try out but still have the problem.
This may also probably be a memory leak that we need to fix because of some undetected logical error when porting to 64-bit but I'm not sure where to start.
Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Compiler: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
OS:  CentOS release 6.4

Comment: What compiler in what version? Maybe you have to play around with optimization levels.

Comment: You could try and use the [x32 ABI](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/).

Comment: So far I've tried compiling using -O2 or Os it's still the same runtime scenario.  Actually using -O2 made the binaries huge compared to not using it.

Comment: What is the size of binary? Did you try to use `strip` on them to reduce their size?

Comment: Hi Kerrek SB, could you briefly describe what x32 ABI does? (even if I wiki it already)...

Comment: Yes I did try stripping the binaries, it drastically reduced the binary size. Before stripping it was about 238 MB after stripping it went down to just 4.1MB! However, during runtime, it still uses a lot of memory same as before.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ... I imagine some [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) .... Also upgrade your compiler to [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8) and use `-fsanitize=address` and perhaps  `-fsanitize=thread`

Comment: Does the 32-bit version of the program also create the same number of threads?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, we will try the valgrind and see if it can help us.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes the 32-bit version creates the same number of threads.  I must clarify that the number of threads is the total threads created by 24 binaries in our system and the threads are only about 4000 (still a lot).  I am isolating the problem to just one binary for now since one binary can create a few hundred threads already and this one binary is showing this alleged memory leak and therefore other binaries are unable to run. The threads mostly are for listening to messages spawned by the message broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for the suggestions guys. The problem lies within the code of the software. It's a bug when porting to 64-bit. The code uses unsigned int instead of size_t when dealing with str.find() in C++. unsigned int is 32-bit while size_t is 64-bit.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

size_t find (const string& str, size_t pos = 0) const;

The while() loop (see below) always evaluates to be true because when -1 is passed to an unsigned int (see Line B) it becomes the highest value of unsigned int for 32-bit.  It will never be equal to npos which is the highest value of size_t for 64-bit. Thus the infinite loop causing very high CPU usage plus the infinite push_back() causing very high memory.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

It says:
This constant (std::string::npos) is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is an unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable value for this type.

```
            **//unsigned int strPos1 = 0;
            **//unsigned int strPos2 = 0;
            size_t strPos1 = 0;
            size_t strPos2 = 0;

 Line A       **while ( strPos2 != str.npos )**
            {
 Line B         **strPos2 = str.find( ",", strPos1 );**
               tokens.push_back(str.substr(strPos1, strPos2 - strPos1));
                    strPos1 = strPos2 + 1;
            }
```

I'm going to have to check on the other binaries for similar cases because they are also having memory leaks.  This porting from 32-bit to 64-bit actually gives a lot of possible memory leaks in the code.

Answer (score 1):

As you reported in the comments, you have a lot of symbols within the executable. Most likely you're using lots of templates with debug information linked in. `strip` can reduce this as well as [playing with the linker flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

The big problem is not the executable size. **It's the crazy amount of threads you're instantiating**. Unless you're running on a super computer with thousands of CPUs, you should (must) redesign your program to use much less threads.

Each thread has its own stack, multiplying the stack size with 10240 gives a huge memory footprint.

There's also a limited number of threads that can run on a given system.

As a bonus, a program with a sane number of threads will run faster. You should not have more than N worker threads (N=logical core count).

**Edit:**

You can use more threads (up to 2N) if each thread does a lot of I/O which is a blocking operation. As an example, compilation of C++ code will be faster when using 1.5N cores as compilation involves a lot of I/O.

Comment: The number `2N` seems completely arbitrary. For example if threads spend 90% of their time blocked on I/O, then `10N` would seem reasonable if the memory is available. The memory used for stack by each thread can be influenced with `pthread_attr_setstacksize` or even controlled with `pthread_attr_setstack`, provided that you can determine your max stack usage.

Comment: In theory you may be right, but mostly when having an I/O intensive workload, adding more I/O will only make things slower. N or 2N are just rules of thumb. Thread count is very workload dependent. The main message here that having 10K threads is not reasonable for non super computer systems.

Comment: I don't really think of "spending 90% of the time blocked on I/O" as necessarily being "I/O intensive". For me, that happens more commonly because the I/O is slow to respond rather than because its bandwidth is saturated. The questioner could of course run tests to determine whether having very many threads is actually helping or not in a particular case (probably you're right and it doesn't). Further, if I/O is the issue then async I/O might beat threads anyway, and generally uses far less memory.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not saying you're wrong. You're probably referring to network operations.

Comment: @egur: If you have 10K threads trying to access a disk, you have even bigger problems.

Comment: @egur: It might be okay to have much threads (although I also think 10K is far too much). If you can design your system to have the much threads have a limited stack depth so you can give them a small stack. This can be done by letting them only do the I/O wait and if I/O is ready have a small number of worker threads that have a big stack and do the complicated stuff.

Comment: @MSalters - your comment suggests that I somehow encouraged using 10K threads. I used very clear wordings in my answer :)

Comment: @RüdigerStevens: modern OSes do not allocate (commit) all the stack at once. They allocate a few pages followed by a guard page(s). whe na guard page is hit, the OS commits more pages. This may eat up a lot of virtual address space but having 48bit of address space it should be fine. **I think we all agree that the problem is having 10K threads**.

Comment: Ok I have to clarify that it is only about a total of 4000 threads across 24 binaries/standalone executable created mainly for listening to messages. Will have to verify if this is done by the message broker (omniORB and an in-house messaging broker) or by the app itself.